# Zoom in and out photos and videos

Tags: codenameone

How can I programmatically zoom in and zoom out a photo or a video (both in case stopped and in the case of playback) when displayed inside a Codename One container?

The container should have a fixed dimension, so the zoom can crop the image or the video.

My use case is a square container in which a photo or video can be zoomed and moved with the finger when enlarged and cropped (even during playback). It’s a feature similar to an Instagram feature.

I suppose that it’s necessary a custom Component to implement this. Thank you for your suggestions, I hope that it’s not too much hard to implement.

**Update of the question with two examples:**

*Note 1*: the photo and the video are not actually cropped, but they seem cropped when the photo or the video are zoomed to fill all the width space.

*Note 2*: there is a small Button in the bottom left of the photo and of the video that allows to zoom in and zoom out the photo or the video. There are only two levels of zoom: the "default" zoom fills all the available width space (cropping the photo or the video), the other zoom makes the photo or the video fitting in the available space. The button allows to switch between these two zoom factors.

*Note 3*: the button allows the video to be zoomed during its playback (second example)

**Example 1 of zooming, moving and cropping a static photo:**

[image]

**Example 2 of zooming and cropping a video during its playback:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented with `ImageViewer` and its `getCroppedImage` method. You can paint a square overlay on top to achieve the shape or override `calcPreferredSize()` to force the size of the viewer.

Comment: Thanks Shai, this approach might be good for photos, but not videos. By the way, `ImageViewer` allows me to set the zoom to code level? I updated my question by adding three notes and two sample videos to explain what I mean: could you please expand your answer by considering these two videos and the notes I added? Thank you for your support

Comment: You can manipulate image viewer zoom level dynamically in code. Yes, you're right we don't have zooming/cropping for video. You might be able to achieve that by creating a layout that plays the video in a region that's larger than the view area in a layered layout. That way you won't see the areas that are physically cropped. The container would need to return the cropping preferred size to accomplish this.